# If-else ladder not entering "else" when no conditions match

Tags: awk

I'm writing my first large awk script with an Ubuntu emulator, and I'm running into a strange problem -- my code won't enter the "else" in the following if-else ladder.

```
BEGIN {
  SECTION_RECORD=0;
}

/STATS_START/,/STATS_END/ {
  if ($0 !~ /STATS_START/) { SECTION_PRESENT="1"; }
  else if ($0 !~ /STATS_END/) { SECTION_FINISHED="1"; }
  else {
    SECTION_RECORD=SECTION_RECORD+1;
  }
}

END {
  print SECTION_PRESENT;
  print SECTION_FINISHED;
  print SECTION_RECORD;
}
```

I'm reading the following input file.

```
=== STATS_START ===
this is a stat
this is another
a third stat
=== STATS_END ===
```

I expect the output of this program, since the section was started and finished with 3 records, to be:

```
1
1
3
```

but instead, I get:

```
1
1
0
```

I have confirmed via a print statement (which I removed from this example for clarity) that the "else" is never entered. I ran this script with the "--lint" and "--posix" options, and it's running without warnings or errors.

I'm really scratching my head here. The code seems right, but I'm guessing that there's something about awk that I missed in the GNU docs that's causing this. Can any awk gurus help me figure out where I'm going wrong, please?

Thanks!

Comment: `!~` means "doesn't match". You want `~`, "matches"

Comment: The amount of time I spent staring at this, argh! Thank you! It's always something small and stupid, no matter how experienced of a programmer you are. Thanks for the extra pair of eyes! :)

Comment: No problem! You can make it easier for yourself next time by adding print statements to see where the script starts to diverge from what you expected, which in this case would be when `STATS_START` causes it to enter the `SECTION_FINISHED` clause instead. This narrows down the problem a lot more than only comparing the expected and actual final output.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you find yourself using any kind of `not` operator, stop and THINK if you can write the code using a positive instead of a negative condition. That will make your code clearer and avoid the chance of you ending up with a double negative (as in your code where `if ! ... else ! ...` - may actually be a triple negative!) which is extremely hard to understand and likely to produce a bug.

Also never use range expressions like `/start/,/end/` as they make trivial code very slightly briefer but then require a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions for anything the tiniest bit more interesting, always use a flag variable instead.

Finally, don't use all upper case for variable names to avoid clashes with builtin variable names.

So, step 1 is to make all your variables lower case, get rid of all the redundant `;`s, and format it to be more readable using GNU awks `-o-` to pretty-print the code:

```
$ awk -o- -f tst.awk > v1.awk
$ cat v1.awk
BEGIN {
        section_record = 0
}

/STATS_START/, /STATS_END/ {
        if ($0 !~ /STATS_START/) {
                section_present = "1"
        } else if ($0 !~ /STATS_END/) {
                section_finished = "1"
        } else {
                section_record = section_record + 1
        }
}

END {
        print section_present
        print section_finished
        print section_record
}
```

Now lets write it without a range expression:

```
$ cat v2.awk
BEGIN {
        section_record = 0
}

/STATS_END/ {
        in_section = 0
        section_finished++
}

in_section {
        section_record++
}

/STATS_START/ {
        in_section = 1
        section_present++
}

END {
        print section_present
        print section_finished
        print section_record
}
```

See how much clearer and simpler it is and how we only test the conditions once each? And now to run it on your sample input:

```
$ awk -f v2.awk file
1
1
3
```